# Length of a group presentation

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

I'm having trouble understanding how to find the length of a group presentation. By a presentation of a group $G$, I mean a representation of $G$ by generators and relations. In "[On the complexity of matrix group problems, I](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/715919)" (1984) Babai and Szemerédi define the length of a presentation to be "the total number of characters required to write down all relations. (Although it does not matter, we may agree that exponents are written in binary.)"

So, for example, if I have the following presentation $G$ for the alternating group of degree $5$ due to Carmichael $${G} = \langle x,y,z\mid {x^3} = {y^3} = {z^3} = {(xy)^2} = {(xz)^2} = {(yz)^2} = 1\rangle$$
would its length be: $3 + 3(3) + 4(3) = 24$? And how does one write this length in binary?

Comment: The whole point about this measure is that we are only interested in orders of magnitude, and so minor differences do not matter. I think we ought to use spaces to separate relators, so I reckon the characters needed are x11 y11 z11 (xy)10 (xz)10 (yz)10 which I think comes to 32 characters.

Comment: Note that this measure doesn't take into account the encoding space needed for elements of the group themselves (it looks to be assumed that every group member can be written in a single character) but, again, this is (generally) swamped by the other facets of the group presentation and should contribute only an additional logarithmic factor to the size.

Comment: Hi Derek Holt. Could you please explain how does this amount to 32 characters?